# Chrome extension automatic update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have a Chrome extension, which we are hosting on Google Storage. The extension is usually applied to a bigger number of Chromebooks via the Google Admin Console.

Most of the time everything works fine, but two issues keep appearing for a smaller group of users:

1. Automatic update does not work - When a new version is deployed and the update.xml is updated, most users will get the new version, but often there is a small group (for example 10% of all), which do not get updated.
2. Similar to the first issue - sometimes when an organization unit has the extension applied from URL#1 and we remove said extension and apply the same extension (same ID) from URL#2 (the version is incremented), the first extension remains; the second one is not installed even though the Chromebook policy has URL#2.

I'd appreciate any tips you might have. Thanks